# Radio button label click timing on safari

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, safari

I have this situation on a form :

```
<form id="boxselection" method="POST" action="select.php">
    <label class="labels" for="boxtype">
        <input type="radio" name="boxtype" value="3x80">
        <img src="...">
    </label>
    <label class="labels" for="boxtype">
        <input type="radio" name="boxtype" value="4x80">
        <img src="...">
    </label>
</form>
<script>
    $('.labels').on('click',function() {
        $('#boxselection').submit();
    });
</script>
```

in Chrome, Firefox and IE everything works correctly, in Safari the PHP script doesn't receive any POST value.

A workaround that works is to modify the javascript this way :

```
<script>
    $('.labels').on('click',function() {
        setTimeout( function() {
             $('#boxselection').submit();
        }, 1000);
    });
</script>
```

this is now working, my question is...why?

Comment: Weird, cause there isn't a `setTimeut` method 8-)

Comment: Just tried your code without the "workaround" and it worked on safari. which OS are you using? and which version of safari are you using?

Comment: Yosemite on a MacBook Air, preinstalled Safari. Going to check the exact version and let you know

Comment: @Coulton of course it was a typo, corrected

Comment: I was only kidding :o)  Hopefully my answer helps.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I think that you need to add `id` values to your radio buttons so that the labels are associated with their respective radio buttons.  The `for` attribute associates itself with the `id` of a form element.

```
<form id="boxselection" method="POST" action="select.php">
    <label class="labels" for="checkbox1">
        <input type="radio" name="boxtype" id="checkbox1" value="3x80">
        <img src="...">
    </label>
    <label class="labels" for="checkbox2">
        <input type="radio" name="boxtype" id="checkbox2" value="4x80">
        <img src="...">
    </label>
</form>
```

As for the jQuery `on.()`,the most likely reason that it works after `setTimeout` is that the radio button hasn't actually changed immediately after the click of the 'label' on the page, even now that it is properly associated with the radio button by the `id`.

You want to add your delegate to the `change` event of the radio button itself, which will also work when you click the label button:

```
$('form#boxselection').delegate('change', 'input[type="radio"]', function(e) {

    $('#boxselection').submit();
});
```

The above code will fire the form submit on the change event for any radio button in your form.

Comment: Didn't know labels where associated with IDs, I'll try your solution. Thanks.